# Pagination on Home Page (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm having an issue trying to get pagination to work on the homepage of a site I'm working on.

The "Older" and "Newer" links show correctly, and it updates the url to reflect the page number but the posts content remains the same as it does on the first page when flipping through the pages.  Here is the code I'm using, simplified of course:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
else { $paged = 1; }

$get_featured_posts = new WP_Query( array(
'posts_per_page'        => 9,
'post_type'             => 'post',
'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
'no_found_rows'         => true,
'paged'                 => $paged,
'offset'                => 5
 ) );

while( $get_featured_posts->have_posts() ):$get_featured_posts->the_post();

<h3 class="entry-title entry-added">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute();?>">    <?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h3>
<p class="short_description"><?php echo short_description('...', 16); ?> </em></p>
<p class="read_more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></p>

<?php
     endwhile;
?>
    <?php 
     // Reset Post Data
     wp_reset_query();
     ?>
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
```

Can't seem to figure out what the problem is, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do we really need `wp_reset_query` here ?

Comment: No, not totally necessary.

Comment: Please remove it and try.

Comment: Just tried it, still no luck.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem thanks to @milo on the WordPress exchange.  Turns out there are special considerations when using "offset" and pagination.  [Check this link for more details](https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination).

Answer (score 0):

try to use `wp_reset_postdata();` instead of `wp_reset_query();` and also updated condition for `$paged`.

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $get_featured_posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page'        => 9,
    'post_type'             => 'post',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
    'no_found_rows'         => true,
    'paged'                 => $paged,
    'offset'                => 5
     ) );

    while( $get_featured_posts->have_posts() ):$get_featured_posts->the_post();

        <h3 class="entry-title entry-added">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute();?>">    <?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h3>
        <p class="short_description"><?php echo short_description('...', 16); ?> </em></p>
        <p class="read_more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></p>

        <?php
        endwhile;
        // Reset Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
?>
```

Comment: Hmm, still the same result.  Maybe I should post the whole code?  Perhaps there's something I'm editing out that shouldn't be.

Comment: Not sure, why don't you try plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/ Its easy and no need to worry about custom queries.

Comment: Ha, yeah I've been using it.  Unfortunately it works great on the archive pages but has the same problem I'm facing when I use it on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this and insert that code of pagination on your page and remove newer and older links

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-add-pagination-to-wordpress